# Fill odd sequences between ones in binary vector with value

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

I'm looking for a vectorized solution for this problem :
Let `A` a vector (great size : > 10000) of 0 and 1.

Ex :

```
A = [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 etc]
```

I want to replace the 0 between the 1's (of odd ranks) by 2
i.e. to produce :

```
B = [0 0 0 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 0 0 0 1 2 2 1 0 0 1 2 1 etc]
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done quite easily with [**`cumsum`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html?refresh=true) and [**`mod`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html):

```
A = [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1]
```

**Short answer**

```
A( mod(cumsum(A),2) & ~A ) = 2
```

---

```
A =   
     0   0   0   1   2   2   2   2   2   1   0   0   0   1   2   2   1   0   0   1   2   1
```

You requested to fill the islands of **odd rank**, but by changing `mod(...` to `~mod(...` you can easily fill also the islands of **even rank**.

**Explanation/Old answer:**

```
mask1 = logical(A);
mask2 = logical(mod(cumsum(A),2))

out = zeros(size(A));
out(mask2) = 2
out(mask1) = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

try using `cumsum`

```
cs = cumsum( A );
B = 2*( mod(cs,2)== 1 );
B(A==1) = 1;
```